# После обновлении Android studio и его библиотеки выводится ошибка

Tags: java, android, gradle

**Обновил Android Studio и его библиотеки(gradle, SDK, java, ...) и ещё изменил package, после этого выходит ошибка**

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**buil.gradle(:app)**

```
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId MPrayer
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 6
        versionName '3.5.1' //new version
        multiDexEnabled true  //ADD THIS LINE

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.github.msarhan:ummalqura-calendar:1.1.9'
    implementation 'net.alhazmy13.hijridatepicker:library:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0'

    implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0"


    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'



}
```

**gradle version >  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
#пожалуйста помогите**

Comment: Откройте `Project Structure->SDK Location` и в поле `JDK Location` выберите путь к установленной JDK11 (в выпадающем списке может быть вариант `Embedded JDK: <path>` - это должно подойти, но если вы "балуетесь" со сборкой из командной строки, то лучше JDK11 установить в систему и прописать в `JAVA_HOME`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Gradle Plugin 7.0 требует для работы JDK 11. Об этом сказано в [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#7-0-0).

Поменяйте Gradle JDK c 8 на 11 в настройках Android Studio: `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK`:

[image: screenshot]